# Symfony 2 SOAP CLIENT

Tags: php, symfony, soap, client

Please tell me why i must put `"\"` before `\SoapClient`. When i delete `"\"`, then i have a error.

```
public function indexAction($name)
{

    try {
            $client = new \SoapClient('some WSDL', array('trace' => 1));
            $a = array('Login'=>'1', 'Password'=>'1', 'LetterNo'=>'1');
            $response = $client->__soapCall('GetTracking', array($a));
            ladybug_dump($response->GetTrackingResult->Status);
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage(), $client->__getLastResponse()); die();
    }
    return array('response' => $response);
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: It would be a good idea to catch \Exception instead of \SoapFault in Symfony2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

...because your controller is in a namespace, so your call to instantiate SoapClient without the root slash tries to load that object from the current namespace.

`App\Controller\SoapClient` instead of `SoapClient`.

You can use a `use` statement at the top of your controller to bring it into scope. `use SoapClient;` and you'll be good to go.